# Sqlite3: How to check date input

Tags: sqlite

I created a table tb with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tb (name TEXT, dt TEXT DEFAULT (date('now', 'localtime')));
```

Then a wrong date was inserted into `tb` on purpose:

```
INSERT INTO tb(name, dt) VALUES("somebody","2015-99-99");
```

It worked without any warning, and with `SELECT * FROM tb` I got:

```
somebody|2015-99-99
```

The `date()` function showed that the input was wrong, (`SELECT DATE(dt) FROM tb` returned nothing), but at the time of inputting we did not know the error.

Is it possible for sqlite3 to check if a timestamp input is correct or not?

(Sqlite version: 3.9.1)

Comment: You declared the field as `TEXT`, so why should SQLite complain? If you want to store as text, do the check yourself outside SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check a field, use a CHECK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tb (
  name TEXT,
  dt TEXT DEFAULT (date('now', 'localtime')) CHECK (date(dt) IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Comment: `date()` returns NULL for invalid inputs.